# trouble with operator overloading in baseclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Hi I'm having some trouble with inhertance and operator overloading and I'm hoping you guys can give me some clarity.

I have the following classes:

```
template<typename Type>
class Predicate{
public:
    Predicate() {};
    virtual ~Predicate(){};
    virtual bool operator()(const Type & value) = 0;
    virtual bool operator()(const Type * value){ //<-- this is the operator thats not working
        return (*this)(*value);
    };
};

template<typename Type>
class Always : public Predicate<Type>{
public:
    bool operator()(const Type & value){return true;}
    ~Always(){};
};
```

Now I want all my predicates to accept both references and pointers, but when I test the classes in:

```
int main(){
    Always<int> a;
    int i = 1000;
    a(&i);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:10:6: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  a(&i);
      ^
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
predicates.h:22:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool Always<Type>::operator()(const Type&) [with Type = int]' [-fpermissive]
  bool operator()(const Type & value){return true;}
```

Comment: _'Now I want all my predicates to accept both references and pointers'_ May be this `return (*this)(*value);` should use an appropriate `static_cast<>` then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you are declaring:

```
bool operator()(const Type & value){return true;}
```

in the subclass, you are *hiding*/*shadowing* any other overload of the operator in the superclass.

If you add:

```
using Predicate<Type>::operator();
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38b9058952a61f49)

in the subclass, everything will work fine.

---

On a side note, I think that allowing both `const&` and `const*` is a design smell. You should just allow the `const&` version and let the user of your class do `*ptr` if they have a `ptr` pointer.

Comment: I fully agree with the comment about design smell, even though I didn't mention it in my own answer. There are a few other problems, e.g. the use of `system("pause");`.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, this is part of a howwork and its always good to learn something extra. 

the predicates are to be used on a vector<Type*> and thats why the need to act on pointers, now it might be that those pointers should be encapsulated in smart pointers but for some reason my university teaches according to old standards and we havent gotten to that.

the part about system("pause") is just cause i had to switch to VS to <regex> to work, it will disapear

Comment: Do not write off raw pointers as "old and bad". They are still the tool of choice in many scenarios where you only need them for navigation with no additional ownership semantics. Teaching only smart pointers is almost as bad as teaching only raw ones.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, what do you mean by "only need them for navigation", exactly?

Comment: @Jeffrey: When you take a pointer from someone else without assuming ownership of the pointed-to object, especially not having any business with its eventual destruction.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, why would you do that (taking a pointer from someone else ownership)? If the ownership is not yours, the interface to that owned object should provide you with references to it, not pointers.

Comment: @Jeffrey: a couple of reasons, e.g. not being able to store references in standard containers or not being able to express "nothing" (null).

Comment: @ChristianHackl, nope. Not a reason. See [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). Prior to C++11 and C++14 (TS) respectively, you could use `boost::reference_wrapper` and `boost::optional`.

Answer (score 0):

Templates and operator overloading obfuscate the real problem here. Look at this small piece of code which yields the same error:

```
void f(int &);

int main()
{
  int *ptr;
  f(ptr);
}
```

The compiler won't let you pass a pointer where a reference is expected. This is what you try to do with your derived class. As you operate on a concrete `Always`, the base versions of `operator()` are not considered.

Look how the situation changes when you operate instead on a pointer (or reference) to the base class:

```
int main(){
    Predicate<int> *ptr = new Always<int>;
    int i = 1000;
    (*ptr)(&i);
    delete ptr;
}
```

This compiles fine because the base-class operators are now considered for overload resolution. But this is just to make you understand the problem better. The *solution* is to apply the [Non-Virtual Interface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). Make your operators non-virtual and implement them in terms of private virtual functions:

```
template<typename Type>
class Predicate{
public:
    Predicate() {};
    virtual ~Predicate(){};
    bool operator()(const Type & value) { return operatorImpl(value); }
    bool operator()(const Type * value) { return operatorImpl(value); }

private:
    virtual bool operatorImpl(const Type & value) = 0;
    virtual bool operatorImpl(const Type * value) {
        return (*this)(*value);
    }
};

template<typename Type>
class Always : public Predicate<Type>{
public:
    ~Always(){};
private:
    bool operatorImpl(const Type & value){return true;}
};
```